# "proved a much lengthier task" or "was proved TO BE a much lengthier task"?

Tags: sentence-construction, ellipsis

> But, though Æthelbert, king of Kent, was duly converted to Christianity and Augustine was soon able to establish the seat of his bishopric at Canterbury, the permanent establishment of Christianity throughout England **proved a much lengthier task** and one which required the active intervention of Celtic missionaries from Ireland and Scotland.
>  <sup>Book- David Daiches, A critical history of English literature
> Pg. No. 6.</sup>

I think it should be:

> The permanent establishment of Christianity **was** proved a much lengthier task.

or

> The permanent establishment of Christianity **was** proved **to be** a much lengthier task.

But in the book it is written "the permanent establishment of Christianity throughout England proved a much lengthier task..."

Is this correct, only writing 'proved'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly correct. *Proved to be = turned out to be*

See [this definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prove).

*Prove* can mean *test* as well as *demonstrate the truth of.*